# I want to change jquery function to pure javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code already working but i want to jquery fucntion convert to pure JavaScript

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.product-addon-add-mattress option').hide();
  $('#pa_bed-size').change(function(){

  var bedSize = $(this).val();
  
  $('.addon option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().indexOf(bedSize) == 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
  })
  
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_bed-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_bed-size" >
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="single" class="attached enabled">Single</option>
    <option value="small-double" class="attached enabled">Small Double</option>
    <option value="double" class="attached enabled">Double</option>
    <option value="king" class="attached enabled">King</option>
    <option value="super-king" class="attached enabled">Super King</option>
</select>



<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-2696-add-mattress-0">
    <option value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option>Not Required</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="double">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="king">(King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
</select>
```

please help me how to change pure javascript and im doing  click the first select box and changing another select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/65ysvqb7/

**JS Code**

```
 var pa_bed_size = document.getElementById("pa_bed-size");

 pa_bed_size.addEventListener("change", function(){
   var bedSize = pa_bed_size.value;
   var addon_select = document.getElementById("addon_select");

   var addon_options_length = addon_select.options.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < addon_options_length; i++){
     if(addon_select.options[i].value != bedSize){
      addon_select.options[i].disabled =  true;
    }
   }
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
  <select id="pa_bed-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_bed-size" >
   <option value="">Choose an option</option>
   <option value="single" class="attached enabled">Single</option>
   <option value="small-double" class="attached enabled">Small Double</option>
   <option value="double" class="attached enabled">Double</option>
   <option value="king" class="attached enabled">King</option>
   <option value="super-king" class="attached enabled">Super King</option>
  </select>



 <select class="addon addon-select" id="addon_select" name="addon-2696-add-mattress- 0">
  <option value="">Select an option...</option>
  <option>Not Required</option>
  <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
  <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00) 
  </option>
  <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
  <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress 
 (£145.00)</option>
  <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress 
 (£185.00)</option>
  <option  value="double">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
  <option  value="king">(King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
  <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00) 
  </option>
  <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00) 
  </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: thanx harsh_apache its work. you save my life

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding✌️

Answer (score 0):

Made a couple tweaks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446496 to make it actually work:

https://jsfiddle.net/dcanning/xfghazdu/3/

**HTML**

```
<select id="pa_bed-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_bed-size" >
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="single" class="attached enabled">Single</option>
    <option value="small-double" class="attached enabled">Small Double</option>
    <option value="double" class="attached enabled">Double</option>
    <option value="king" class="attached enabled">King</option>
    <option value="super" class="attached enabled">Super King</option>
</select>



<select class="addon addon-select" id="addon_select" name="addon-2696-add-mattress-0">
    <option value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option>Not Required</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="single">(Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="small-double">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option  value="double">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="king">(King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option  value="super">(Super King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var pa_bed_size = document.getElementById("pa_bed-size");

pa_bed_size.addEventListener("change", function(){
   var bedSize = pa_bed_size.value;
   console.log(bedSize);
   var addon_select = document.getElementById("addon_select");

   var addon_options_length = addon_select.options.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < addon_options_length; i++){
   console.log('option:' + addon_select.options[i].value)
    if(addon_select.options[i].value != bedSize){
      addon_select.options[i].disabled =  true;
    } else {
      addon_select.options[i].disabled =  false;
    }
   }
});
```